# 3D PDF : howto convert VRML with colors to U3D or PRC?

Tags: pdf, 3d, media9

I'm using media9 package and it is great! 
What I'm trying to get is to have a 3D PDF coming from one or more VRML objects.
I cannot find anymore the DeepExploration sw
http://www.righthemisphere.com/products/dexp/

I tried Meshlab 1.33 and 1.34 beta obtaining a colored u3d object and 3D pdf, but with this method I cannot have nor a multi object 3d pdf nor assign/change a correct light source...
I followed this tutorial http://rainnic.altervista.org/content/embed-3ds-pdf-latex-u3d which works fine with a STL (no colors, just a single object) but with a VRML I cannot change the light source...

Is there a free or open source solution to obtain that?
Thanks
Maurice

Answer (score 0):

[www.daz3d.com](http://www.daz3d.com) which is freeware (as in beer) may be of help.

Comment: thanks for the tip... ..  any opensource or script solution? thanks again